# Get y-axis max/min value based on array using floating point numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, math

I have been using a script I put together to calculate the y-axis Min/Max label for a SVG/HTML5 Canvas graph when given an array.

e.g [124, 721, 361, 297, 177, 21] y-axis Min label = 0 | y-axis Max label = 750

It has been working great with integers but doesn't work with float values.
How can I get this working with float values?

These are the functions I am using to calculate Min and Max values

```
// Calculate y-axis Max label value
function yMax (numArray) {
    var max = getMaxOfArray(numArray);
    var yRange = getRangeOfArray(numArray);
    var yPow = Math.pow(10, yRange.toString().length - 1) /2; 
    // (/2) division added for more accurate result 
    return Math.ceil(max / yPow) * yPow
}

// Calculate y-axis Min label value
function yMin (numArray) {
    var min = getMinOfArray(numArray);
    var yRange = getRangeOfArray(numArray);
    var yPow = Math.pow(10, yRange.toString().length - 1) ;
    return Math.floor(min / yPow) * yPow 
}
```

I have included my script of useful math functions which I have referred to..

```
// Get Max value from array
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

// Get Min value from array
function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
}

// Get Range of array
function getRangeOfArray (numArray) {
    var max = getMaxOfArray(numArray);
    var min = getMinOfArray(numArray);
    return max - min;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `yRange.toString().length` to `1 + Math.floor(Math.log(yrange)/LOG10);` where `LOG10` is a constant that only needs to be initialized once as `LOG10 = Math.log(10);`. This will work for floating points and have the same behavior over integers.

Comment: This Works great, although there is a lack of support for Math.log10(). breaking it down to                                                                         Math.log(yRange) / Math.log(10) instead may work, i need to get the most support i can

Comment: Seem to getting some strange results with a test array -  [41.273, 41.272, 41.261, 41.283, 41.291] i'm getting 41.300000000000004 as the max and not 41.3

Comment: @navigator As to your above point, I made the edit. As to your second point, it looks like a rounding error (these tend to happen with floating point calculation). I'd suggest formatting your number before displaying it. Maybe something like `toPrecision(8)` or `toExponential()`.